# Adding/appending additional information in a column for a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

EDIT:

I need to store/add/append additional information in a specific column in a csv file with out using `csv.DictReader`.

If I wanted to skip a row in a column and it was empty, what do I need to do for it?

For example:

Sample csv file:

```
$ cat file.csv
"A","B","C","D","E"
"a1","b1","c1","d1","e1"
"a2","b2","c2","d2","e2"
"a2","b2","c2",,"e2"
```

Code:

```
sample = ['dx;dy']
with(openfile.csv, "r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    headers = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        #sample.append(to the column D)
```

The Output should look like this:

```
$ cat file.csv
    "A","B","C","D","E"
    "a1","b1","c1","d1;dx;dy","e1"
    "a2","b2","c2","d2;dx;dy","e2"
    "a2","b2","c2",,"e2"
```

Comment: `sample = ['dx';'dy']` is invalid syntax. Please fix this. Did you mean `sample = 'dx;dy'`?

Comment: Yes sorry thats what i meant

Comment: Can you also specify how you know you want to append to column `"D"` and what character to separate the existing value and the new value by? My answer assumes both these are given.

Comment: Thank you Pranav! <3 If i wanted to skip a row for appending the column what would I need to do? PLease see my edit

Comment: See what you get in `row` for that third row (either by printing the rows as you read them, or by stepping through your code in a debugger). How would you check if the `value` is equal to that?

Comment: it should be if value == "":

Comment: Right! And you only want to make the modification if that is _not_ the case, so do `if value != "": new_value = ..., row[col_index] = ...`

Comment: Btw, empty strings are [falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/843953), so you could just do `if value` instead of `if value != ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the header of the column you want to append to, you can find its index in the `headers` row, and then modify *that element* of each `row`.

```
append_to_column = 'D'
separator = ';'
sample = ['dx;dy']
with open('file.csv', "r") as csvfile, open("outfile.csv", "w") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    headers = next(reader)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    col_index = headers.index(append_to_column)
    for row in reader:
        value = row[col_index]
        new_value = value + separator + sample[0]
        row[col_index] = new_value
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Which gives:

```
A,B,C,D,E
a1,b1,c1,d1;dx;dy,e1
a2,b2,c2,d2;dx;dy,e2
```

Note that this file doesn't have quotes because they aren't required, since the fields don't contain any commas. If you want to force the `csv.writer` to write quotes, you can add the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` argument to the `csv.writer()` call, like so: `writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)`
Then, you'll get:

```
"A","B","C","D","E"
"a1","b1","c1","d1;dx;dy","e1"
"a2","b2","c2","d2;dx;dy","e2"
```